# How to vertically align undersets?

Tags: vertical-alignment

How to vertically align the numbers beneath (with `\underset` or otherwise)?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\underset{1}{x}=\underset{1}{p_{A|B}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

**Update**: This should go into a tabular, which `stackunder` doesn't seem to be doing well:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a longstack (stacktype L).  EDITED to use `\normalbaselineskip` instead of `\baselineskip`, so that it can appear in `tabular`, if needed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\stacktype{L}
\setstackgap{L}{.7\normalbaselineskip}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\stackunder{x}{\scriptstyle1}=\stackunder{p_{A|B}}{\scriptstyle1}
\end{equation}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\stackunder{x}{\scriptstyle1}=\stackunder{p_{A|B}}{\scriptstyle1}
&
\stackunder{x}{\scriptstyle1}=\stackunder{p_{A|B}}{\scriptstyle1}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, sorry I did not mentions this should go into a tabular...

Comment: @dzeltzer Use `\normalbaselineskip` instead of `\baselineskip`, since the latter is zeroed out inside `tabular`.

Comment: Thanks. Off topic: what graphics format should I use for non-pixelized output?

Comment: @dzeltzer eps (and eps converted into pdf) are capable of vector format.

Answer (score 6):

This is an opportune time to use `\vphantom`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \underset{1}{x} = \underset{1}{p_{A|B}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \underset{1}{\vphantom{p_{A|B}}x} = \underset{1}{p_{A|B}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```